# Mapbox iOS SDK polyline, swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapbox

Mapbox SDK with swift 3.0 doesn't draw a polyline.

(Swift 2.3 works fine)

Swift 3 version:

```
for coord in coordsArray! {

                    let lat = coord.array?.first?.double
                    let lon = coord.array?.last?.double

                    let point = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!)

                    coordsArrayValues.append(point)
                }
                completionHandler(coordsArrayValues)
```

In completion handler method:

```
var rectangle: MGLPolyline?

    var coordsArrayValues = coordinatesArray

    // draw a route

    rectangle = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &coordsArrayValues, count: UInt(coordsArrayValues.count))

    if let rectangle = rectangle {
        complection(rectangle)
    }
```

Here is what debugger says in about MGLPolyline and coordsArrayValues:
(lldb) po coordsArrayValues
▿ 8 elements
  ▿ 0 : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    - latitude : 37.609333999999997
    - longitude : 55.750295000000001
  ▿ 1 : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    - latitude : 37.609400999999998
    - longitude : 55.750410000000002
  ▿ 2 : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    - latitude : 37.609442999999999
    - longitude : 55.750495000000001
  ▿ 3 : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    - latitude : 37.609763000000001
    - longitude : 55.751038999999999
  ▿ 4 : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    - latitude : 37.609966999999997
    - longitude : 55.751409000000002
  ▿ 5 : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    - latitude : 37.610123999999999
    - longitude : 55.751694000000001
  ▿ 6 : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    - latitude : 37.610168000000002
    - longitude : 55.751823999999999
  ▿ 7 : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    - latitude : 37.610219999999998
    - longitude : 55.751918000000003
,

.

Later on I call it:

```
self?.routeService.getRoute(coordinatesArray: coordinates, complection: { [weak self] polyline in
            self?.output.showRoute(polyline: polyline)
        })
```

In ViewController it is simply added as an annotation:

```
func showRoute(polyline: MGLPolyline) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.mapView.addAnnotation(polyline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you set the value of polyline and call showRoute()?

Comment: @picciano , the value of polyline was added with rectangle and then put into completion handler. later it just moves into the view like that: self?.routeService.getRoute(coordinatesArray: coordinates, complection: { [weak self] polyline in
                self?.output.showRoute(polyline: polyline)
            })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with pod update (from Mapbox 3.3.5 to 3.3.6 version).